# Uso de switch case para escolha de uma função

Tags: c, switch

Gostaria de usar o switch case para escolher qual função irá prosseguir com o programa.

O programa tem 3 funções: uma função soma, outra multiplica e a ultima é responsável por escolher qual função o usuário irá escolher. Segue o trecho do programa:

```
float escolhaFuncao (int escolha){

 switch (escolha) {
 case 1:
    float SomaDigitos (float soma_A, float soma_B);
    break;
 case 2:
     float Multiplicacao (float num1, float num2);
     break;
 default:
    printf("numero nao permitido");
    break;
 }

return (escolha);
}
```

Não sei se esse método é o mais eficiente, na verdade to aprendendo a trabalhar com funções, o programa está fluindo corretamente, fazendo a soma e a multiplicação, só gostaria de saber qual método eu usaria para o usuário escolher se quer usar a função soma ou a função multiplicação.

**Caso necessite que eu poste o código completo, me avisem que edito a postagem, não postei logo pois minha duvida é somente nessa função.**

Answer (score 0):

esta correto essa forma de usar o switch case, porem não sei dizer se esse programa funcionaria, pois soma_A,soma_B, num1 e num2 não estão sendo recebidos de nenhnum lugar(se forem variaveis globais funciona, mas é bom evitar variavel global). é necessario salvar esse resultado para poder dar o `return`, seria algo do tipo

```
float escolhaFuncao (int escolha,float a, float b){
    float resultado;
    switch (escolha) {
    case 1:
        resultado = SomaDigitos (a, b);// não tem necessidade por o tipo da variavel ao chamar a função
        break;
    case 2:
        resultado = Multiplicacao (a, b);
        break;
    default:
        printf("numero nao permitido");
        break;
    return resultado;
    }

main(){
    ...
    resposta = escolhaFuncao(escolha, a, b)
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Bacana, não tinha pensado nisso, vou testar o programa com essas mudanças e volto para te informar se obtive êxito

Comment: não consegui, vou reescrever todo o código e tentar novamente

Comment: realmente não funcionou.